# How to use regex in notepad++ in this condition?

Tags: notepad++

I want to search strings in notepad++ such as NullpointerException, AnotherException and all other exceptions except JmsException or ConnectException , but currently I have "(connect|jms)Exception" and its only searching JmsException and ConnectException. What do I add to this regex to make it work?

Comment: Do you only want it to find those specific exceptions, or are you looking for a solution that catches anything with a pattern of "<Word>Exception"?

Comment: @MattChampion I want to find all exceptions except JmsException and ConnectExcption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with:

Find what: `(?<!Jms)(?<!Connect)Exception`

Make sure that `Regular Expression`  is checked.

`(?<!....)` is a negative [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use `(?Exception)(!connect|jms(Exception))(\w+)`

Comment: Invalid regular expression